# Attendance List

Tags: members

I need to create an attendance list.  I will be adding a over a 100 members to my expression engine installation and I want to be able to track their attendance to my events.  I as an admin want to be able to check off which members attend today (so and so event).  How can I accomplish that?

I also want to be able to go back and look at a grid and see every member and what days they attended.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One practical way I can suggest is to use one of the add-ons that allows you to have members as entries (profile edit, safecracker registration, zoo visitor are the ones that come to mind).  Then it would be fairly straight forward for you to, at the event level, use a relationship field to indicate who was in attendance.  There's nothing that will display a grid showing the information the way you're seeking within the control panel out of the box, but creating a template that lists your events and within each event, uses the relationship field to display the attendees you recorded would be fairly straight forward. This of course assumes that you are entering your events as entries in EE as well.